# Diff Check With Simple Summary Output

Tags: python, list, compare, diff

I am new to Python and want to write a diff check program that performs the basic diff check on two lists of input (from file) and then outputs differences in summary form.

For instance, some of the summary stats would be:

1. A list of what is in A but not B
2. A list of what is in B but not A
3. Number of duplicates in each list

This will primarily be used to do asset discovery reconciling on networks, so the lists will be full of IPs or Hostnames. My main ask is for help getting started doing this.

I apologize if this has been asked already, but I can't find what I am specifically looking to do anywhere here.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Joseph, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two you can just do set comparisons:

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
>>> B = ['q', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'c']
>>> sorted(set(A) - set(B))
['a', 'd']

>>> sorted(set(B) - set(A))
['q', 'r']
```

For the 3rd, you can use the `Counter` from the `collections` library, which creates a dictionary counting the number of appearances of each item in an iterable:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> {k: v for k, v in Counter(A).items() if v > 1}
{'a': 2}

>>> {k: v for k, v in Counter(B).items() if v > 1}
{'b': 2}
```

For "Anything else that becomes relevant over time" - you'll have to be more specific!

Comment: Thank you! forget about 4, it's just a place holder for my own use